# Is there a way to split a grouped dataframe by size?

Tags: r, dplyr

`table_by_size <- original_df %>% group_by(grouping_factor) %>% group_split()` gives a nice, clean `list_of` of the split data from original data.frame.

`original_df %>% group_by(grouping_factor) %>% summarize(counts = n())` is a very easy way to count the size of all groups.

`original_df %>% group_by(grouping_factor) %>% filter(n() == <size #>)` enables me to filter out groups of specific sizes.

Is there a way for me combine all of these and split a grouped data-frame based on group size? So, split all groups of size `n` as one item. All groups of size 3 as one, all groups of size 4 as one and so forth.

A simple alternative is using a loop to go through `n()` and make sub-frames manually but before I do that I wanted to see if there is a tidyverse method to do this.

It's all almost there in `dplyr` but by the looks of it one cannot customize how `group_split()` does the splitting, is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Add the size as a column and split by that:

```
metabolite_table |>
  mutate(group_size = n(), .by = grouping_factor) |>
  group_by(group_size) |>
  group_split()
```

The names are a bit confusing in this case. Assuming `grouping_factor` has a more meaningful name, I'd suggest giving `group_size` a similarly meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

How about, for example,

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(GroupSize = n()) %>% 
  group_by(GroupSize) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = FALSE)
```

Comment: That was it! New to `tidyverse` and keep forgetting about mutate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
original_data_frame |> 
  mutate(n = n(), .by = grouping_factor) |> 
  group_split(n)
```

Also works.

[Credit to](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/15i45b4/comment/jus2jkv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)